# s3api getobject permission denied

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to fetch a file from s3 using aws-cli

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket <bucket_name> --key /foo.com/bar/summary-report-yyyymmdd.csv.gz temp_file.csv.gz --profile <profile_name>
```

but I am getting the following error -

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
```

I've rechecked my configuration using

```
aws configure --profile <profile_name>
```

and everything seems to be correct there. I am using the same credentials to browse and fetch the file on S3 browser without any issue.

Documentation is of minimal use as I have very limited access to this bucket. I cannot verify the permissions or use

```
aws s3 --profile <profile_name> ls
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`AccessDenied` can mean you dont have permission but its the error returned if the object does not exist (you can read [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2041) for the reason why to use this error)

You can make sure you have access to the bucket using the `aws s3api list-objects` command like

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket <bucket_name> --query 'Contents[].{Key: Key, Size: Size}' --profile <profile_name>
```

Most probably in your case the issue is with the user of `/` in front of the key

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket <bucket_name> --key foo.com/bar/summary-report-yyyymmdd.csv.gz temp_file.csv.gz --profile <profile_name>
```

Comment: Yep. found the problem with "/" few minutes back. Corrected it and then saw your answer. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was kms access. I found this helpful:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/